# About lock behavior when update row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking, increment

Now, I'm trying to increment number sequential in SQL Server with the number provided from users.

I have a problem when multiple user insert a row same time with same number.

I try to update the number that user provided to a temporary table, and I expect when I update the same table with same condition, SQL Server will lock any modified to this row until the current update finished, but it not.

Here is the update statement I used:

```
UPDATE GlobalParam 
SET ValueString = (CAST(ValueString as bigint) + 1) 
WHERE Id = 'xxxx'
```

Could you tell me any way to force the other update command wait until the current command finished ?

This is entire my command :

```
DECLARE @Result bigint;

UPDATE GlobalParam SET ValueString = (SELECT MAX(Code) FROM Item)

DECLARE @SelectTopStm nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @ExistRow int

SET @SelectTopStm = 'SELECT @ExistRow = 1 FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM Item WHERE Code = '999') temp'
EXEC sp_executesql @SelectTopStm, N'@ExistRow int output', @ExistRow output

IF (@ExistRow is not null)
   BEGIN
      DECLARE @MaxValue bigint

      DECLARE @ReturnUpdateTbl table (ValueString nvarchar(max));
      UPDATE GlobalParam SET ValueString = (CAST(ValueString as bigint) + 1)
      OUTPUT inserted.ValueString INTO @ReturnUpdateTbl 
      WHERE [Id] = '333A8E1F-16DD-E411-8280-D4BED9D726B3'
      SELECT  TOP 1 @MaxValue = CAST(ValueString as bigint) FROM @ReturnUpdateTbl
      SET @Result = @MaxValue
END
ELSE
   BEGIN
      SET @Output = 999 
   END
END
```

I write the codes above as a stored procedure.

Here is the real code when I insert one Item:

```
DECLARE @IncrementResult BIGINT

EXEC IncrementNumberUnique 
    , (some parameters)..
    ,@Result = @IncrementResult OUTPUT

INSERT INTO ITEM (Id, Code) VALUES ('xxxx', @IncrementResult)
```

I create 3 threads and make it run at the same time.

The return result :

```
Id   Code
1    999
2    1000
3    1000
```

Thanks

Comment: When you try this update, the row with `Id = 'xxx'` will in fact be exclusively locked for the time it takes to update its value, and then that lock will be released once the transaction commits (or rolls back). Only that **one row** you're updating - not the whole table. So a second `UPDATE` command for another row (with a different `Id` value) will be able to proceed - and that's a **good thing!**

Comment: @marc_s: thanks about reply. 
But I have two threads that try to update this row (same Id),  I don't know why the second update don't wait the first finished.
I already tried with ROWLOCK but I still get the duplicated values

Comment: Just this "atomic" `UPDATE` **will** force the second thread to wait - but is this really your *entire* statement ? Could it be that you have a `SELECT` first? That wouldn't be locked ....

Comment: @marc_s : I posted entire statement. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: As suspected - it's just not a single atomic `UPDATE` _ therefore it's prone to duplicates (as you've seen). So why aren't you just letting the database handle all these messy details by using an `INT IDENTITY` column and be done with it ????

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements, try `ROWLOCK` hint to tell the optimizer to start with locking the rows one by one as the update needs them.

```
UPDATE GlobalParam WITH(ROWLOCK)
SET ValueString = (CAST(ValueString as bigint) + 1) 
WHERE Id = 'xxxx'
```

Comment: I already tried with ROWLOCK, but I still got the duplicated value

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL Server does `READ Committed` locking which releases `READ` locks once the read operation is committed. Once the `Update` statement below is complete, all read locks are released from the table `Item`.

```
UPDATE GlobalParam SET ValueString = (SELECT MAX(Code) FROM Item)
```

Since your `INSERT into Item` is outside the scope of your procedure. you can run the thread in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level. Something like this.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

DECLARE @IncrementResult BIGINT
EXEC IncrementNumberUnique 
, (some parameters)..
,@Result = @IncrementResult OUTPUT

INSERT INTO ITEM (Id, Code) VALUES ('xxxx', @IncrementResult)
```

Changing the isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` will increase blocking and contention of resources on `item` table.

To know more about isolation level, refer [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

you should look into [identity columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and remove such manual computation of incremental columns if possible.